# Free Tide prediction service - World (a freeware program would work as an alternative)

Tags: geolocation, noaa

Is there a free service where I could input a GPS location and it would return me the current tide situation at the position? 
As an alternative - some library / program that does the exact thing one could integrate? For my app I am currently using the public-domain, accurate NOAA predictions, but these are limited to the US. :(
Several apps provide that data and I am curious what their source is.

Comment: http://tidespy.com/client/TideFrameSignup.php

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the client is not free. I am interested in the raw data and dont plan to display adds.

Comment: Will be country by country then, UK has https://www.bodc.ac.uk/data/online_delivery/ntslf/raw/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is tide prediction somehow integrated in the wavewatch3 modeling pipeline? I'm considering to install that anyways.

Comment: T still did't find a solution for this problem? I believe there should be a free catalogue out there somewhere, no?